# Have both distinct and count

Tags: postgresql

I have a table users(id and name) and order(cost and user: FK to users).

```
users.name users.id
bob               1
alice             1
```

and

```
orders.user orders.cost
          1          15
          1           5
          2           4
          1           4
          1           3
          1           3
          2           3
```

Here is a query which joints users and orders and sorts by order cost.

```
users.name users.id orders.user orders.cost
bob               1           1          15
alice             1           1           5
bob               2           2           4
alice             1           1           4
alice             1           1           3
alice             1           1           3
bob               2           2           3
```

If I were to do a `distinct on` user (in Postgresql), I would get

```
users.name    cost
bob              15
alice             5
```

I actually want the counts, while still being sorted on highest order cost/

```
users.name    count
bob               3
alice             4
```

Comment: Are we talking about a single table `foo` or two tables `users` and `order` in a 1:n relationship like in the accepted answer? Not the same thing. And different caveats, too. Actual table definitions showing data types and constraints and your version of Postgres are the way to go.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter a high-rep user edited my question assuming a single table. I did mean it for joined tables.

Comment: I see, that was a misleading edit. Now, if you consider the rest of my comment: `Actual table definitions showing data types and constraints and your version of Postgres are the way to go.` Table definitions include data types and constraints, like a complete `CREATE TABLE` statement. And in case you are not aware of your Postgres version: `SELECT version();`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I will not post undetailed questions going forward. I use an ORM and migration manager so I am rusty in both DDL and SQL. Is there something to help?

Comment: pgAdmin shows complete DDL scripts. Or provide the output of `\d+ tablename` in psql (not a `CREATE TABLE` script, but also complete information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand, but I guess something like:

```
select u.name, count(*)
from users u
join order o
    on u.id = o.user
group by u.name
order by max(o.cost) desc
```

would do. Please include your query and if relevant, table definitions for future questions.

Comment: Could you explain the order by? I'm ordering on highest unique cost.  I'm trying it out myself.

Comment: I tried max() for order by and it seems to work by my observations.

Comment: A `desc` to the order by is also necessary.